# Inbuilt function clearInterval is not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, clearinterval

I am learning `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `clearInterval` functions.

now I tried to write such code, but `clearInterval` is not working.
Code:

```
<h2>Hello!</h2>
<p>i am a paragraph</p>
<button onclick="setInterval(messageOnInterval, 110)">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(messageOnInterval)">Stop</button>
<script>
    function messageOnInterval() {
        
        var p=document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = "i am a paragraph";
            document.body.appendChild(p);
        
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign `setInterval` to a variable to get it's handle which is in number format, then you can call `clearInterval` to clear that timer.

You cannot assign a function to `clearInterval`.

So it should be like this:

```
<script>
    function messageOnInterval_Impl() {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = "i am a paragraph";
        document.body.appendChild(p);

    }

    var intervalHandle;
    function setMessageOnInterval() {
        intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
            messageOnInterval_Impl();
            // ... 
        }, 110)
    }
</script>

<h2>Hello!</h2>
<p>i am a paragraph</p>
<button onclick="setMessageOnInterval()">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(intervalHandle)">Stop</button>
```

Comment: 1-question: why would you StackOverflowers write code so complicatedly?
Example:   
   you wrote this:
 `function setMessageOnInterval() {
        intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
            messageOnInterval_Impl();
            // ... 
        }, 110)
    }`

you could write so:

 `function setMessageOnInterval() {
        intervalHandle = setInterval(messageOnInterval_Impl, 110)
    }`

anyway thank you!

Comment: 2-question: i tried to do again (reviewed code), but mine is not working. I am looking at the code, but don't understand where i am mistaken

    `function addParagraph(){
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML='I am a new paragraph';
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }

    var var1;
    function repeatF(){
        var1 = setInterval(addParagraph, 500);
    }
    
</script>

<h2>Hello!</h2>
<p>i am a paragraph</p>
<button onclick="setInterval(repeatF, 500);">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(var1);">Stop</button>`

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't understand how to add comment so if it could be read normally

Comment: 3-question: maybe i skipped some subjects on JS? what should i read, going back to tutorials?

Comment: worked out 
    `function addParagraph(){
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML='I am a new paragraph';
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }

    var var1;
    function repeatF (){
        var1 = setInterval(addParagraph, 500);
    }
    
</script>

<h2>Hello!</h2>
<p>i am a paragraph</p>
<button onclick="repeatF();">Click Me</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(var1);">Stop</button>`

Comment: 1- it's not complicated, it's just scoped. you'll need to use the way i provided if you'll need passing arguments to the actual implementation logic when setInterval is created. both correct.

2- you're still creating interval in your onclick event. that creates a new instance of setInterval so we lost it's handle there. meaning that we got no reference to clear it.

3- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp (completely read it, do not fast scroll)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns a value that needs to be used when calling `clearInterval`. You don't pass the function as arg, but the value returned by an earlier call to `setInterval`

```
id = setInterval(messageOnInterval, 110)
clearInterval(id)
```

In your case you should declare a JS variable inside a `script` and use that as your id.

Note: this will not properly work if you press the button multiple times, as you'll lose older `setInteval` returned values.